# What does this thread_local RNG seed accomplish?

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, thread-local

As part of an assignment, one of my professors gave me code that looks kind of like this:

```
namespace
{
  thread_local unsigned seed; // for use with rand_r

  void run_custom_tests() {
      // set this thread's seed
      seed = 0;

      // insert some random numbers into a map
      std::map<int, int> m;
      for (int i = 0; i < key_max; ++i)
          m.insert(i, rand_r(&seed));

      auto random_operations = [&]()
      {
          // do more stuff with rand_r(&seed)
      };

      std::thread t1(random_operations);
      std::thread t2(random_operations);
      t1.join();
      t2.join();
  }

} // end anonymous namespace

void test_driver()
{
    run_custom_tests();
}
```

My question is what is the purpose of that `thread_local` seed? I understand that you can't allow two threads to access the same global variable. But why not just make it local? Since `seed` is only used to fill that map and inside the lambda, and each thread has its own stack, wouldn't a local variable accomplish the same goal?

I did fine on the assignment, since the point wasn't to understand this usage of `thread_local`. But I'm still confused by this aspect of the program.

Comment: A local variable declared inside `random_operations`, yes. If it's declared in the outer scope, these threads would share it because lambda captures it by reference.

Comment: Is this function is the only one where you generate random numbers, and is it only called *one* time in the whole program (one time during running the program, not at one location in the code)? If yes, it makes no difference. Else, the previous values influence the next ones...

Comment: @milleniumbug so then would changing the lambda to capture `seed` by value solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the linux documentation:

> Like rand(), rand_r() returns a pseudo-random integer in the range [0, RAND_MAX]. The seedp argument is a pointer to an unsigned int that **is used to store state between calls**.

Earlier in the documentation it is mentioned that `rand` and `rand_r` are not thread-safe.

Therefore the state must either be separated per thread or the call must be protected with a mutex.

ref: http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r

Comment: I know. But since each thread has its own stack, why can't the seed just be a local variable? That is what I asked in my question.

Comment: @Max He could have had the seed be local to the lambda, but then he'd have to make the lambda mutable because it would be modifying its own state. Maybe he didn't want to have to explain that part of the language?